# Как в Notepad++ удалить строки, в которых нет одновременно строчных и прописных латинских букв и цифр?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Как удалить строки, в которых нет одновременно строчных и прописных латинских букв и цифр (спец. символы, например кавычки, запятые или вопросит. знаки, не имеют значение), а также все те, длина которых меньше 8.

Например, будут удалены такие строки:

```
jkjhuih67,2
23jfkcm5
,.,kj8f83
86758493
38tfgDE
iiiiiiiiiiii4
,.,.,...,,.,.,@
```

При этом такие удалены **не будут**:

```
jkkJUISD7fgffb
,,,,cHDYU3.,gfgtr
7843834UsDSDs
ddddDfdiuy788
DDDDDdfdD4545TTGF
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}`?

Comment: Не понял условие "только из строчных латинских букв ИЛИ / И цифр ИЛИ символов, также все, длина которых менее 8 символов.". Что значит ИЛИ / И цифр ИЛИ символов?

Comment: "Это значит, что любая строка, содержащая менее 8 символов, будет удалена." При этом "ddddD" не удаляется в примере

Comment: Прошу прощения. Отредактировал.

Comment: Сохраняются лишь те строки, в которых цифры комбинируются с прописными и строчными буквами (могут быть добавлены символы), длина которых не меньше 8 символов.

Comment: "Сохраняются лишь те строки, в которых цифры комбинируются с прописными и строчными буквами (могут быть добавлены символы)". Что значит могут быть добавлены символы? Цифры и буквы - это тоже символы. Какие конкретно символы, кроме цифр и латинских букв, могут быть?

Comment: А что такое спец. символы? `,.@` - это "спец. символы"? Если да, то почему будут удалены `,.,kj8f83`, `jkjhuih67,2`. В них >= 8 символов, среди которых латинские буквы, цифры и "спец. символы"

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос с помощью кнопки "править", а не пишите в комментариях, потому что у вас несоответствие между вопросом и комментариями

Comment: Вопрос отредактирован. Эти строки будут удалены потому, что не содержат прописных латинских букв.

Comment: Вот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/1559788/10743113, только добавьте {8,} для 8+ повторений

Comment: Жаль, что нельзя дать ответ на русском языке.

Comment: Данное регулярное выражение не работает. Оно выделяет, и те строки, которые подлежат удалению, и те, которые подходят по критериям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте следующее выражение, для захвата нужных строк:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]?).{8,}/m
```

Учтите, что флаг `i` не должен быть использован, только лишь `m`.

[См. демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/OR3ExI/2).

Так как у меня нет Notepad, я буду использовать на примере Sublime Text. Допустимо использование отрицательной опережающей проверки (negative lookahead assertion) с этим выражением, изменив регулярное выражение в следующий вид:

```
(?!(^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]?).{8,}))^.+$
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И делать простую замену на пустоту для удаления этих ненужных строк.

**P.S.** Мой вариант не считается идеальным, но вроде как он работает.

Comment: Увы, ваш алгоритм не работает. Он не находит строки вида asdfghjkl1, хотя они не соответствуют критериям: нет прописных латинских букв.

Comment: @yandashkov, думаю это связано с учетом регистра, попробуйте сделать с ним манипуляцию.. [Подробнее](https://superuser.com/questions/810546/how-to-make-smart-highlighting-case-sensitive-in-notepad).

Comment: @yandashkov, в Sublime Text все прекрасно работает, когда включен параметр case sensitive (ALT+C).

Comment: А есть какие-то программы, которые могут более простым скриптом это сделать? Я не знаю, какую сделать манипуляцию: скрипт выглядит сложно.

Comment: @yandashkov, просто смотрите решение тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547201/force-regex-to-be-case-sensitive

Comment: Возможно, Notepad++ не может удалять строки с подобным «размытым» условием.

Comment: @yandashkov, просто следуйте инструкции, здесь нет размытого условия. Уберите галочку match case

Comment: Спасибо. Всё нормально.

Comment: @yandashkov, если задача решена, можете принять мой ответ (нажав на зеленую галочку рядом с ним).